# No nonzero proper ideals of $K$-algebra $A$ implies the ring $A$ has no nonzero proper ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, noncommutative-algebra, rngs

This is from Seth Warner's *Classical Modern Algebra*.

The problem is:

> If $A$ is a nontrivial $K$-algebra possessing no nonzero proper ideals, then there are no nonzero proper ideals of the ring $A$. [Hint: show that a nonzero ideal of the ring $A$ contains the submodule generated by $A^2$.]

According to the book: An ideal of an algebra $A$ is a subset of $A$ that is both an ideal of the ring $A$ and a $K$-submodule of $A$. In other words, a nonempty subset $C$ of a $K$-algebra $A$ is an ideal if and only if for all $a$, $b$ in $C$, for all $x$ in $A$, and for all all $e$ in $K$, the elements $a+b$, $xa$, $ax$, and $ea$ belong to $C$.

Thanks.

Comment: Is $K$ an arbitrary ring?

Comment: as far as I can tell yes

Comment: What is the difference between an ideal of $A$ as a $K$-algebra and an ideal of $A$ as a ring?  I don't understand the question.

Comment: we are looking at an ideal of an algebra and an ideal of a ring. those are different concepts

Comment: An ideal of an algebra is usually just *defined* to be an ideal of the underlying ring.  But this definition makes your problem trivial so we assume you have a different definition.  Please tell us what it is.

Comment: Oh good, so I'm not losing my mind after all...

Comment: according to seth warner: an ideal of an algebra A is a subset of A that is both an ideal of the ring A and a submodule of the module A.  I edited my question to include this definition.

Comment: I think you are confused, to say a subset I of A is an ideal of the ring A and to say I is a submodule of A as an A-module are equivalent.

Comment: Assuming that you mean left ideals and left modules, or right ideals and right modules, or two-sided ideals and bimodules, then an ideal of a ring is automatically a submodule of the ring, in fact that's one way of defining ideals.  So we are again led to the fact that an ideal of an algebra is just an ideal of the ring.

Comment: Here's an example from the book: The R-vector space becomes a trivial R-algebra when multiplication is defined by xy=0; Q is then an ideal of the trivial ring R but is not an ideal of the trivial R-algebra R

Comment: @Seth. I don't mean a subset I of A as an A-module. I mean a subset I of A as a K-module.   So if you have a K module A  and an ideal I of the ring A, then in order for I to be considered an ideal of the K-algebra A, it must be true that I is a K-module

Comment: I think it would be good (given the answer below and the comments to it) to be clear about unital assumptions. Since the two notions of ideal are clearly equivalent when either rings or $K$-algebras are always assumed unital (since $A$ is assumed to be in both categories), I suppose the question is in fact the following. **Let $K$ be a ring, and $A$ a non-unital $K$-algebra. If $A$ considered as a non-unital ring has a proper nonzero two-sided ideal, then so does $A$ considered as $K$-algebra.** Also be clear about whether $K$ itself is assumed unital and/or commutative. Or correct my guess.

Comment: @Marc Van Leeuwen. I'm using standard definitions with no additional or hidden assumptions. So yes, K is unital.

Comment: I just edited my post to include additional verbiage from the book.

Comment: @user my fault. I just accepted more answers. I'm new to stackexchange so I'm still learning the ropes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be a *unital* $K$-algebra, and $I$ an ideal of $A$. Then $I$ is also a $K$-submodule of $A$: take $a\in K$ and $x\in I$. Then $a*x=a*(x\cdot 1_A)=x\cdot(a* 1_A)\in I$. (Here $*:K\times A\to A$.)

If $A$ **is not unital**, as the question suggests and some comments require, let's consider $I$ a nonzero ideal of $A$. Let $J=\{x\in A:xA\subseteq I\}$. Then $J$ is an ideal of $A$ that contains $I$. Moreover, $J$ is an ideal of $A$ as a $K$-algebra, that is, for $\lambda\in K$, $x\in J$, we have $\lambda*x\in J$. This shows that $J=A$ and therefore $A^2\subseteq I$. But $A^2$ is an ideal of $A$ as a $K$-algebra and since the multiplication on $A$ is not trivial we get $A^2=A$, so $A\subseteq I$ and thus $A=I$.

Comment: Please specify whether this is a hint or an answer to _another_ question. Your emphasis makes it clear that you did not overlook the unital hypothesis that you need, but which is conspicuously absent in the question.

Comment: +1 For me rings always have a multiplicative neutral element (placing the burden of extra specification to those who don't agree with Jacobson), so giving this the nod.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I agree about the general use of "ring". But I would not take that to imply that $K$-algebras are automatically assumed to be unital (even though [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field) says so for the case where $K$ is a field, but which OP appears _not_ to assume in this question). And just (in passing) _calling_ a $K$-algebra a ring would seem a rather implicit way to specify that it is assumed unital. Regardless of all this, the formulation of the question seems to make it clear that unital is not assumed here, because it makes the question trivial.

Comment: @user thanks. can you explain why $\lambda*x\in J$ for     $x\in j$ and how that implies $J=A$? also, why do you state multiplication in $A$ is not trivial and how does that imply $A^2=A$?

Comment: @animalcroc First, since $x\in J$ (that is, $x\alpha\in I$ for all $\alpha\in A$) we get $(\lambda*x)a=x(\lambda*a)\in I$. Now, by hypothesis, $J$ has two options: $J=0$ or $J=A$. Since $J$ contains $I\ne 0$, then... Second, a *nontrivial $K$-algebra* means exactly this: the multiplication is not trivial, i.e., not zero! Again $A^2$ has only two possibilities and the non trivial multiplication (there exist $a,b\in A$ such that $ab\ne 0$) ensures $A^2\ne 0$.

Comment: @user silly for me to forget my question included the trivial constraint... but i don't see how by hypothesis, $J$ must be $0$ or $A$. Same with  $A^2$

Comment: @animalcroc What means for you "$K$-algebra possessing no nonzero proper ideals"? For me this means that an ideal of $K$-algebra $A$ has only two options: to be zero or proper (that is, equal to $A$).

Comment: @user. lol, my fault again. for some reason I keep straying from my own question :o

Comment: @user congratulations on receiving the bounty. you are now the premier bounty hunter of the Wild West!

Comment: @user  whoops, check again